# how to recreate app.config.exe.config

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

My program is creating a .exe.config from my app.config and that exe is retaining the changes the user makes to it throughout and after runs of my program.

That's great and all but I want to add a button to my windows forms app that allows users to reset those settings to the original values that are static/manually changed in my app.config.

What is the best way to do this?  This is the entirety of my app.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="CacheDir" value="C:\blah\prod\cache" />
<add key="CheckFilesDir" value="C:\blah\prod\cache\cachefiles" />
<add key="GenerateTo" value="C:\Users\blah\Desktop" />
<add key="CustomVariable1Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="CustomVariable2Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="CustomVariable1" value="" />
<add key="CustomVariableValue1" value="" />
<add key="CustomVariable2" value="" />
<add key="CustomVariableValue2" value="" />
```

Normally access like..

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "C:\\Users\\RJenkins\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\CacheConfigNinja\\CacheConfigNinja\\bin\\Debug\\CacheConfigNinja.exe.config";
//configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "C:\\Users\\RJenkins\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\CacheConfigNinja\\CacheConfigNinja\\bin\\Release\\CacheConfigNinja.exe.config";

Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Comment: Could you add a clean `.config` file as application resource and use it as reset value?

Comment: I don't see why not but I'm looking for the best way as this seems like something people would often have to do.

Comment: How are you **saving** the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the [`Reset()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.reset.aspx) method on your Application Settings.  From the documentation, this method:

> Restores the persisted application settings values to their corresponding default properties.

Comment: I've added my app.config and the way i normally access it.  I'm not sure how to use that Reset() method with my code.

Comment: @user2081737 It should be `Properties.Settings.Default.Reset()`

Comment: Dang yea that's not doing anything for whatever reason.  Maybe I havent set up my app.config in the standard way or something?

Comment: @user2081737 Yeah - saw your access code.  That's not the standard way of working with application settings.  How are you changing setting values?

Comment: @user2081737 For the "normal" way of handling this, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx  This allows app settings to be per user, and will work with the reset method.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Reset()
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload()
```

Comment: For some reason this isn't doing anything.