# My app.config needs to be regenerated

Tags: c#, app-config

I had been editing my `app.config` a little too much to the point where it broke.
Now I've been trying to find a way to regenerate it with the data it had (like it said it required `Newtonsoft.Json` dll).

I've tried to clean & rebuild my solution but that doesn't seem to work.

Do you know how to regenerate it?

Edit: I want to regenerate it because I'm getting errors that say `Unrecognised configuration section userSettings`.

Thanks!

Comment: will you show an app.config? Or we need to guessing?

Comment: @MikkaRin I'm asking if there's a way to regenerate it. Mine now is just the default app.config.

Comment: Check if this solution can work for you:
[Rebuilding app.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399216/rebuilding-app-config-in-visual-studio)

Comment: @JosepB. I tried that but it still shows up as default empty. Thanks anyways,

Comment: A version control system like Git or Subversion would help here. You should post your defect app.config along with your question.

Comment: @Jehof It would, too bad I have none.

Comment: @Jehof I deleted it because I tried the answer that Josep B. gave me.

Comment: Not sure but how about this [how to recreate app.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948711/how-to-recreate-app-config-exe-config)?

Comment: @AshishSrivastava Sadly that didn't work, Thanks for your help anyways!